# PayPal v2 Onboarding error with multiple products

Tags: paypal

I'm trying integrate [PayPal V2 Onboarding](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/) in sandbox.

My call is :

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <My-Access-Token> " \
  -d '{
    "tracking_id": "795_123",
    "operations": [
      {
        "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
        "api_integration_preference": {
          "rest_api_integration": {
            "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
            "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
            "third_party_details": {
              "features": [
                "PAYMENT",
                "REFUND"
             ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "products": [
      "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT",
      "PPPLUS"
    ],
    "legal_consents": [
      {
        "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
        "granted": true
      }
    ]
}'
```

And the response is :

```
{
    "name": "INVALID_REQUEST",
    "message": "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
    "debug_id": "266c1b0e09a8f",
    "information_link": "",
    "details": [{
        "issue": "INVALID_ARRAY_LENGTH",
        "description": "The number of items in an array should not be more than 1",
        "field": "/products",
        "location": "body"
    }],
    "links": []
}
```

Has anyone come up to this error message for "products" array, or is this a PayPal v2 Onboarding bug?

Comment: The error message says to only include one item in the "products" array, so...

Comment: Also note that as the documentation says, "You must be an approved partner to use this integration." (in live mode). If you are an approved partner, PayPal will guide and support you with the integration process -- if you aren't, you can't use this anyway.

Comment: The company i work for is an approved partner. As i said in my previous post, we re upgrading from v1 onboarding (where multiple product are allowed in "products" array) to v2 (where multiple products arren t allowed). Am i allowed only for 1 product in the array by the v2 api? What if i want to add multiple producs?! Thank you.

Comment: PayPal supports its partners so this is a question for them; we can only see what the error message is telling you.